# Is there any way I can tighten my crankshaft pulley without a torquemeter?

Tags: torque, crankshaft, pulley

My crankshaft pulley requires 130 nm (95 lb-ft) of tightening torque. I have a torque meter but it only supports up to 80 nm. I can't afford to buy a separate torque meter just for crankshaft pulley because it is extremely expensive in my area. Is there any way I can apply the same amount of torque and prevent over-tightening? I was thinking about using a 2 meter metal rod and applying 65 nm of torque to it. 65 x 2 = 130 nm.
However, I don't know how to exert such a force on a metal rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a set of hanging scales and a longer bar? 10 foot bar and 9.5lb on the scale... etc

A basic application of force * distance.

Comment: So, using a 3-meter-long rod: 130 / 3 = 43.33 nm (43/33 / 9.8066 = 4.418 kg/m). Therefore, I need a hanging scale, a long rod (3 meters) and 4.4 kg of weight. Am I right?

Comment: Just pull on the scale to get the reading...

Comment: Can I use the same technique to measure how much torque had been applied previously for tightening the pulley?

Comment: Obviously yes... but oem may have had a sealer...